# Qt SQL prepare fails

Tags: c++, sql, qt, qtsql

I'm trying to run this Qt code

```
QString serverName = "localhost";
QString dbName = "zfserver";
QString userName = "root";
QString passWord = "123456";

QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL");
db.setConnectOptions();

db.setHostName(serverName);
db.setDatabaseName(dbName);
db.setUserName(userName);
db.setPassword(passWord);

if(db.open())
{
    QSqlQuery query;
    query.prepare("INSERT INTO account (name, email, password, type) "
                  "VALUES (:name, :email, :password, :type)");
    query.bindValue(":name", "atef");
    query.bindValue(":email", "asfasf@gfasga.com");
    query.bindValue(":password", "123");
    query.bindValue(":type", "2");

    if (query.exec())
    {
        qDebug() << "OK";
    } else {
        qDebug() << "Error" << query.lastError().text();
    }

    db.close();
}
```

But I'm getting this error

> Error "Using unsupported buffer type: 1701601889  (parameter: 1) QMYSQL3: Unable
>        to bind value"

If I change the query without the bindValue it works. Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: 1) QT is a different project. Read the tagwiki. 2) What Qt version is this? 3) What platform is this? 4) What architecture is this? 5) Why are you using QMYSQL3?! 5) Have you checked the return value of prepare? 6) Have you tried to print out the last query?

Comment: I'm using QT Qt 5.2.1 with mingw windows 7, i just downloaded QT and installed it and trying it for first time i don't know how to use another version of QMYSQL3 its the default one, when i change the query to normal query without prepare and bindValue its excuting without errors.

Comment: Can you answer 5-6), please? Also, make sure you do not call addDatabase repeatedly as it should be called only once.

Comment: thanks Laszlo i have fixed this by rebuilding the QT mysql driver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to rebuild the SQL driver .

`QMYSQL3` seems to be old.