# Qt MySQL Query - Unable to bind value

Tags: c++, mysql, qt

I finally fixed my MySQL connection in C++ Qt. However, when I try to bind values, I get the following error:

```
QSqlError("2036", "QMYSQL3: Unable to bind value", "Using unsupported buffer type: 1701052421  (parameter: 1)")
```

I have these files:

Engine.h:

```
#ifndef ENGINE_H
#define ENGINE_H

#include "database/mysql.h"

class engine
{
private:
    static mysql* _mysql;
public:
    static void initialize();
    static void destroy();

    static mysql get_mysql();
};

#endif // ENGINE_H
```

Engine.cpp:

```
#include "engine.h"
#include "entities/member_controller.h"
#include <QDebug>

mysql* engine::_mysql;

void engine::initialize()
{
    _mysql = new mysql();

    member* mem = member_controller::get_member(1);
    qDebug() << "mem name = " << mem->getFirstName() << " " << mem->getSecondName();
    delete mem;
}

void engine::destroy()
{
    delete _mysql;
}

mysql engine::get_mysql()
{
    return *_mysql;
}
```

mysql.h:

```
#ifndef MYSQL_H
#define MYSQL_H

#include <QtSql>
#include <QString>
#include "mysql_result.h"

class mysql
{
private:
    QSqlDatabase db;
public:
    mysql();
    ~mysql();
    mysql_result create_result(QString query);
    QSqlError error();

    QSqlQuery query_prepare(QString query1)
    {
        QSqlQuery query(this->db);
        query.prepare(query1);
//        this->query = query;
        return query;
    }
};

#endif // MYSQL_H
```

(query_prepare body temp. in header file just to test)

mysql.cpp

```
#include "mysql.h"

mysql::mysql()
{
    this->db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL", "QMYSQL");
    this->db.setHostName("localhost");
    this->db.setUserName("root");
    this->db.setPassword("Eequi4");
    this->db.setDatabaseName("test");
    this->db.open();
}

mysql::~mysql()
{
}

QSqlError mysql::error()
{
    return this->db.lastError();
}
```

member_controller.h:

```
#ifndef MEMBER_CONTROLLER_H
#define MEMBER_CONTROLLER_H

#include <QString>
#include "member.h"

class member_controller
{
public:
   static member* get_member(unsigned int id);
   static member* get_member(QString email);
};

#endif // MEMBER_CONTROLLER_H
```

member_controller.cpp:

```
#include "member_controller.h"
#include "database/mysql_result.h"

#include "engine.h"
#include "database/mysql_result.h"
#include <QtSql/QSqlQuery>

member* member_controller::get_member(unsigned int id)
{
    QSqlQuery result = engine::get_mysql().query_prepare("SELECT * FROM members WHERE member_id = :mem_id");
    result.bindValue(":mem_id", id);

    if (result.exec() && result.first())
    {
        return new member(id, result.value("first_name").toString(), result.value("second_name").toString(), result.value("screen_name").toString(), result.value("email").toString(), result.value("status").toString());
    }
    else
    {
        qDebug() << engine::get_mysql().error() << "\n";
        qDebug() << result.lastError() << "\n";
    }

    return new member(0, "", "", "", "", "");
}
```

I hope this is all the code needed. I tried using questionmark except of :mem_id but no luck either.

Comment: Have you tried [rebuilding the SQL driver](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23165805/1771479)?

Comment: You know how I can do that on Windows? I'm sorry if this is a noob question. Does it matter if I build a Qt 5.4 driver and use it in 5.5?

Comment: See: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/sql-driver.html#how-to-build-the-qmysql-plugin-on-windows

Comment: I tried, but make wasn't a recognized program or w/e, so I downloaded GnuWin32 with make.exe, and used it after qmake, but nothing made a new .dll. Maybe I just misunderstand it. With using make, I got the error: make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: look here for compiling: https://fecub.wordpress.com/2014/08/12/compilecreate-mysql-driver-for-qt5-on-windows/

Comment: I see `qDebug() << engine::get_mysql().error() << "\n"; qDebug() << result.lastError() << "\n";` in your code so error message should be 2 lines, but you've posted just one.Please post both.

Comment: try to change  `result.bindValue(":mem_id", id);` to ` result.bindValue(":mem_id", QVariant(id));`

Comment: That didn't work, first error is all empty strings. Second error is what i posted.

Comment: @JoshuaBakker what about converting parameter to `QVariant` type?

Comment: @Alex did what you said but it didn't work unfortunately.

Comment: Absolutely the same error message?

Comment: @JoshuaBakker just found this question on SO : http://stackoverflow.com/a/23165805/4421474 check your driver

Comment: I tried rebuilding the MySQL driver without luck but I will try again since I'm programmer and I'm not about to give up lol.

Answer (score 5):

I am not C++ or Qt expert and have no possibility to debug your code.

But just because of curiosity I've started to investigate your code and found suspicious line (the 2nd one) in your code:

```
mysql_result result = engine::get_mysql().create_result("SELECT * FROM members WHERE member_id = ?");
```

Since I am not expert and you didn't provide any `includes` I don't know neither what is your `engine` namespace nor function `get_mysql()` return type nor `create_result` return.

So I did some guess: `get_mysql()` probably return [`QSqlDatabase`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqldatabase.html) object? isn't it?

But that type does not support any `create_result` method! So I stuck there.

Next thanks to google I've found your [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33018970/qmysql-query-failing) made a week ago. I would please to include such important information in your post next time, so people can see your classes and functions like:

```
mysql_result mysql::create_result(QString query)
{
    return mysql_result(this->db.exec(query));
}
```

and

```
mysql_result::mysql_result(QSqlQuery query)
{
    this->query = query;
}
```

Now I can understand what that 2nd line of your code is trying to do.

The suspicious thing I see here is `return mysql_result(this->db.exec(query));`. That seems according to the function names that you are trying to **execute** query and get **result** from mysql server.

But according to the algorithm I see in your `member_controller::get_member` it seems to me that you are only on **prepare** stage but not executing yet. I see that [Qt documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqldatabase.html#exec) is not clear enough (and again i am not an expert) because: *Executes a SQL statement on the database and returns a QSqlQuery object*. And technically you can say that you have `QSqlQuery` as a result and you can expect that this result is absolutely the same as if you do:

```
//mysql_result mysql::create_result(QString query)
QSqlQuery  mysql::query_prepare(QString query)
{
    QSqlQuery query(this->db);
    query.prepare(query);
    this->query = query;
    return this->query;
}
```

But IMHO it isn't. In your case it is already executed, that is why you can't bind any parameter later. So I would suggest you to change your `mysql_result mysql::create_result(QString query)` or create another function `QSqlQuery  mysql::query_prepare(QString query)` which has more sense to me. and change your first lines of code to:

```
member* member_controller::get_member(int id)
{
    QSqlQuery query = engine::get_mysql().query_prepare("SELECT * FROM members WHERE member_id = ?");
    query.addBindValue(value);

    if (query.exec() && query.first())
...
...
```

And very last point I don't understand why are you trying to reinvent the weel? If you already have Qt mysql classes which looks very good to me why do you create your own class and methods with one line to call Qt method like:

```
void mysql_result::add_parameter(QVariant value)
{
    this->queryObject.addBindValue(value);
}
```

Sorry but IMHO that is not very good idea and has almost no sense.

**UPDATE** Looking into your updated code I see:

```
 result.bindValue(":mem_id", id);
```

where `result` type is `QSqlQuery` so you are calling to the native method `bindValue` where second parameter according to documentation is `const QVariant & val`. So I would change your call to:

```
 result.bindValue(":mem_id", QVariant(id));
```

or

```
 QVariant mem_id(id);
 result.bindValue(":mem_id", mem_id);
```

Comment: **And very last point I don't understand why are you trying to reinvent the weel? If you already have Qt mysql classes which looks very good to me why do you create your own class and methods with one line to call Qt method like:** - Because queryObject isn't public. I like doing it this way except for getQueryObject().addBindValue.

Comment: `public` is just OOP term it has nothing almost nothing common with security. So I still don't see any good reason to make code more complicated. **I like doing it this way** ok, that is your code and your project sure you can do whatever you want and the way you like.

Comment: I mean i dont want a getter for the QSqlQuery object and then call the function from there i'd thought this way it'd be better. But as comments suggested i'll try to rebuild the mysql driver. Engine is a static class which holds all variables of the program all instances etc.

Comment: I see no reason to *rebuild the mysql driver* yet. To test my way it takes just 5 min. Did you try?

Comment: Excuse me, i'm not at home now just keeping track of SO. I'll try either when im on the train with my laptop or when im home.

Comment: Alex I still get the error with using your query_prepare function. Sorry about late response I had vacation and haven't touched my laptop since I got other things to do.

Comment: You should post your question properly with all your code involved to get help here. Nobody can guess your code :-)

Comment: Thanks for the tip Alex, I added almost all the code except for one class (which is useless to post here). I might start another bounty, might be a waste of my rep but I don't think there's a different way.

Comment: That is up to you :-) I will try to help anyway.